# Как сделать пакет для gulp? Структура у плагина такая же как и у gulpfile.js?

Tags: gulp

Я разбираюсь с `gulp` и, возможно, вопрос простой, но: как сделать пакет (плагин) для gulp? Как я понял, это просто отдельный `js` файл со всеми нужными для работы модулями, из которого экспортируются новые функции. То есть по сути, файл плагина формируется как `gulpfile.js`, только называется он по другому? Еще прочел про специальный пакет `gulp-util`, который позволял вести логирование и вызывать ошибки, но в gulp 4 считается устаревшим. Чем его можно заменить?

Comment: https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/using-plugins

Comment: https://gulpjs.com/plugins -> любой плагин, исходник, [например](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: Gulp plugins are Node Transform Streams that encapsulate common behavior to transform files in a pipeline

Comment: возможно, https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/advanced/creating-custom-registries